# How to write an if/else statement to check whether or nor a child element is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Imagine I have a div with a few descendants/children as such:

```
<div class="currenTile" tabindex="0">
  <h1 tabindex="0"> my Header </h1>
  <p tabindex="0"> some text </p>
  <ul tabindex="0">
     <li tabindex="0"> item 1 </li>
     <li tabindex="0"> item 2 </li>
     <li tabindex="0"> item 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to create an "if/else" statement that checks after a keydown event, if an element has focus AND is a child of the 'currentTile' div, to do something. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What element do you want to check?

Comment: I want to check every element inside the parent div. I do not care to target any specific element since at any given moment the parent div could expand to more elements inside of it

Comment: In your example, there is no element which can can be focused.

Comment: @AleshaOleg any element with a tabindex attribute can receive focus

Comment: @Kode_12 ok, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function() {
    var isChildOfDiv = $(":focus").parents("div.currenTile").length > 0;
    console.log(isChildOfDiv); //true if element with focus is within the div, false otherwise
});
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/9rvyps8g/

`$(":focus")` gets the current element with the focus, then we check all of that element's parent with `.parents()`, and pass the div's class to it.

Have in mind that this works as is because there is only one div with that class. I haven't tested what would happen with other divs with the same class, although I assume nothing would happen. If you want only one div, use an ID instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this by doing:

```
if($("#myElement").is(":focus") && $("#myElement").closest(".currenTile").length > 0)
```

Where #myElement is whatever element you are checking. is(":focus") checks if its focused obviously and closest() climbs up the DOM from that element looking for a parent element with that class name

Answer (score -1):

Give your element an ID of 'unicorn' or whatever you want.

```
//Assuming you have keydown event check first

if (document.activeElement.parent().getAttribute("id") == "unicorn") {
//Do Stuff with document.activeElement
}
else {
//Do Different Stuff with document.activeElement
}
```

Depending on your code, there may be a better way to identify what the parent is.

If you want to check all descendants:

```
//Assuming you have keydown event check first
var x = document.activeElement();
var found = false;
while (x=x.parentElement) {
    if (x.parent().getAttribute("id") == "unicorn") {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
     //Do Stuff with document.activeElement
}
else {
     //Do Different Stuff with document.activeElement
}
```

Comment: This only works if the focused element is the direct descendant of the parent. It sounds like in his question the element could be buried further than that under the parent

Comment: I thought he only wanted to check if the element is a child (meaning direct descendant) of the div.

Comment: "I want to check every element inside the parent div."

Comment: [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) doesn't have a `.parent()` method.